# Java / Android Studio : How do I make a method that refer to the button if it is outside the button method?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-button

I am new to Java and learning Android Studio. I am trying to access my button in several functions. My current code is:

```
public static void player1() {
    v.setText("X"); //not working why? how do i do it? #confused

}
public void click (View v) {

}
```

Keep it in mind, I want to access for all the buttons. So not a specific button, that is why I wrote v.setText(). I am trying to make a Tic-Tac-Toe game.

Answer (score 0):

To access any view (Button, TextView, EditText...), first declare a global variable:

```
Button myButton;
```

Then, in onCreate() method, bind this myButton object to your button in XML layout:

```
myButton = findViewById(R.id.myButton);
```

Once this is done, you can simply access your button using myButton object in any function like:

```
public function myFunc1(){
   myButton.setText("Something");
}

public function myFunc2(){
   myButton.DO_SMOETHING
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to access objects in methods is to provide them as arguments, e.g.

```
public static void myFunction(MyClass myObject) {
    myObject.setText("welcome to stackoverflow");
}
```

Then, when you call that method, you have to provide the arguments.

```
MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
myFunction(myObject);
```

Of course, in this example, MyClass would have to provide a method `setText(String)`. If I assume correctly, you're trying to use the `setText`-method on a `Swing View`-Object, right? This won't work, as the View-Class does not provide a `setText()`-method.

My advice to you: Follow some kind of tutorial to learn more about the basics of Java. Also I would recommend to learn Swings successor JavaFX instead.

Good luck with your coding. :)

Comment: `public static void player1 (View v) {
        ((Button)v).setText("X");
        v.setEnabled(false);
    }

    public static void player2(View v) {
        ((Button)v).setText("O");
        v.setEnabled(false);
    }


    public void click (View v) {

            player1(v);
            player2(v);


    }' Thank you! I "solved it", I am now moving on a new step. I cast the v with button because they can't give the setText(); thing